# Javascript method doesn't see object variable

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects, dom-events

```
var Shape = function(type)
{
    this.type = type;

    addEventListener("resize", this.align);
}

Shape.prototype.align = function()
{
    alert(this.type);
}
```

.

```
var variable = new Shape('rectangle');
```

When I resized, I want alert **rectangle** but it alerts **undefined**

Comment: `alert(this)` (or rather log it to the console), what do you see?

Comment: adding to BenG's answer. Under event, *this* will point to *window*

Comment: I see **[Object object]**

Comment: that's because of alert, try console.log instead of alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the scope to use `this` in the `resize` event.

```js
var Shape = function(type) {
  this.type = type;
  addEventListener("resize", this.align.bind(this));
}

Shape.prototype.align = function() {
  alert(this.type);
}


var variable = new Shape('rectangle');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `variable.align()`, since you're creating a new object. By doing so, I get what you're asking for: An alert with `'rectangle'`.

Answer (score 0):

> The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called [[*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)]

[`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value.

```js
var Shape = function(type) {
  this.type = type;
  addEventListener("resize", function() {
    this.align();
  }.bind(this));
  //OR addEventListener("resize", this.align.bind(this));  
}

Shape.prototype.align = function() {
  alert(this.type);
}


var variable = new Shape('rectangle');
```